# 100% width header and footer

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm new to CSS and am designing my first site from scratch using CSS (I've recently graduated from the *for the love of God stop using html to style your websites* way of life).

I want to create a page where the header and footer extends beyond the width of the body copy and goes complete from left to right of the page. I've started the code but I'm stuck. The header will have a logo and the navigation (I haven't coded the navigation yet but that's not too hard) and the footer will simply have one line of content.

I looked up examples in other questions and the answers are all really complicated and involve things like scroll bars and that's way more than what I want.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated! Sorry if this is a stupid question. Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<body>

<!-- begin wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- begin header -->
  <div id="header">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

<!-- begin navigation -->
  <div id="navigation">
    <ol>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

<!-- begin content -->
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

<!-- begin footer -->
  <div id="footer">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow);

#header {
    background: #636769;
}

#navigation {
}

body {
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    background: url(../images/texture.png);
}

#wrapper {
    width: 938px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    background: white;
}

#footer {
   background: #636769;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `#header` and `#footer` to span the entire page, you will also have to move them out of `#wrapper`. You may want to specify height too, e.g. `height: 40px`.

Do you want the header and footer to stay in place while scrolling? If so, use `position: fixed;` on both. Then, on `#header` put `top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;`; and on `#footer` put `bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;`.

Anything else that you want to do, let me know. I'd be glad to help.

Comment: It appears that I have to basically set up divs for any sections that I want, correct? So if I want to have three columns in the main body section of a page those would all need to be individual divs?

Comment: The reason you have to move `#header` and `#footer` out, like @McArthey said is inheritance...explained: if `#wrapper` has a width of `938px` its children (in this case `#header` and `#footer`) with `100%` width equals `938px` (100% of the parent's width)...so its children with `50%` width will have `469px` width...etc. Very helpful when trying to give something `100%` height because you have to give `body` a height of `100%`.

Answer (score 2):

Since your #wrapper class encompasses the entire page then all subsequent tags will inherit the same value.  If you want the #header or #footer to ignore this, then you will need to specify a different value for those classes.  Try and change these classes to specify their own width values (i.e. `width: 938px;`) and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks! I moved <div id="wrapper"></div> to after the header, before the content, and before the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Pull the `header` and `footer` divs outside the `wrapper` to allow them to fit the width of the page.

```
<body>

<!-- begin header -->
  <div id="header">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

<!-- begin wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- begin navigation -->
  <div id="navigation">
    <ol>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    </ol>
  </div>

<!-- begin content -->
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- begin footer -->
  <div id="footer">
    <p>Content</p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! That hadn't occurred to me.